# SPARQL: Bind value to variable based on another value

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a SPARQL query that returns the triples shown in the attached table. Is it by any chance possible to assign the value of "new_arg_val" to variables ?arg1 and ?arg2 based on their "position"-value? The position is from an rdf:Seq, and it should work with an arbitrary length of the rdf:Seq.

[image: Result]

**Edit:**
So I am working on an approach to handle the inferencing of calculated properties, ie. properties that are derived from the values of other properties. I am using the [seas evaluation ontology](http://ci.emse.fr/seas/EvaluationOntology-1.0) and the structure of my data is the following:

```
<resourceURI> seas:fluidTemperatureDiffeence <propertyURI> .
<propertyURI> seas:evaluation <evaluationURI> .
<evaluationURI> seas:evaluatedValue "33 Cel"^^cdt:ucum ;
              prov:wasGeneratedAtTime "2017-06-13T21:51:26.706+02:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
              seas:calculation "abs(?arg1-?arg2)"^^xsd:string ;
              prov:wasDerivedFrom _:c0 .
 _:c0 a rdf:Seq ;
      rdf:_1 <evaluationURIa> ;
      rdf:_2 <evaluationURIb> .
```

A property can have multiple evaluation as properties can change over time. Hence I also have several calculations. So far my query looks like this:

```
SELECT  *
WHERE
  { #Get the time of the latest calculation
    { SELECT  ?calculatedProperty (MAX(?_tc) AS ?tc)
      WHERE
        { GRAPH ?g
            { ?resource seas:fluidTemperatureDifference/seas:evaluation _:b0 .
              _:b0 ^seas:evaluation ?calculatedProperty .
              _:b0  prov:wasGeneratedAtTime  ?_tc
            }
        }
      GROUP BY ?calculatedProperty
    }
    #Get calculation data
    GRAPH ?gi
      { ?calculatedProperty
                  seas:evaluation       _:b1 .
        _:b1      prov:wasGeneratedAtTime  ?tc ;
                  seas:calculation      ?calc ;
                  seas:evaluatedValue   ?old_res .
        _:b1     (prov:wasDerivedFrom)+ _:b2 .
        _:b2  ?position  ?old_arg
      }
    #Get the time of the latest input values
    { SELECT  ?old_arg (MAX(?_t) AS ?t)
      WHERE
        { GRAPH ?g
            { ?old_arg ^seas:evaluation/seas:evaluation ?arg .
              ?arg  prov:wasGeneratedAtTime  ?_t
            }
        }
      GROUP BY ?old_arg
    }
    #Get argument data
    GRAPH ?g
      { ?old_arg ^seas:evaluation/seas:evaluation ?new_arg .
        ?new_arg  prov:wasGeneratedAtTime  ?t ;
                  seas:evaluatedValue   ?new_arg_val
      }
    #Bind values to arguments (WIP)
    BIND(IF(?position = rdf:_1, ?new_arg_val, "") AS ?arg1)
    BIND(IF(?position = rdf:_2, ?new_arg_val, "") AS ?arg2)
    #Should do the calculation based on ?calc
    BIND(str("newResultHere") AS ?_res)
    #Get datatype of existing result
    BIND(datatype(?old_res) AS ?datatype)
    #Get unit of existing result
    BIND(strafter(str(?old_res), " ") AS ?unit)
    #Define datatype and unit for result
    BIND(strdt(concat(str(?_res), " ", ?unit), ?datatype) AS ?res)
    #Make a guid (struuid() bug in stardog)
    BIND(replace(str(uuid()), "urn:uuid:", "") AS ?guid)
    BIND(uri(concat("https://host/proj", "/Evaluation/", ?guid)) AS ?evaluationURI)
    BIND(now() AS ?now)
  }
```

I would like to get a calculation result so I can construct the new triples.

Comment: Your question seems to be very interesting, but it is not easy to understand what you exactly want. Please provide some example data and the output desired.

Comment: Thank you. I will add it to my original post.

Comment: It would be better if you add this to your question instead of the comment

Comment: Note, input data and expected output makes problem descriptions much easier. In addition, this allows people to test their solutions on your sample data.

Comment: I made the edit now. I hope it is clear what I would like to achieve.

Comment: MadsHolten, as well as I understand, you want to "evaluate" the `seas:calculation` value, i. e. to write something like `BIND(eval("abs(?arg2-?arg1") AS ?res`).  Unfortunately, it is not possible. Probably `seas:calculation` is just an annotation property or the ontology was intended to be used with special pre- or postprocessing software. And, of course, it is possible in SPARQL to subtract the last value of `rdf:Seq` from the first etc.